# Cognitive Search response cutoff since the content is too long

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm working on a project which needs cognitive search to return a bunch of json data. But that json data is kind of long and the response is only a part of the whole string. Is there a way to show the remaining string or increase the length of the response?

Comment: Could you edit your question to share an example of what the REST API response looks like? The service doesn’t truncate field values as it returns them, so I’m wondering if something else is going on.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Thank you for your answer. The problem is solved. It was caused by Excel's cell limitation. Saving as csv works for Cognitive Search without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is your response in this case? I have had some cognitive search return some very big responses to apis without any issues. Could the client you are using be trimming the response? What happens when you try this call on the Azure portal directly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is solved. It was caused by Excel's cell limitation. Saving as csv works for Cognitive Search without any issue.